# Best way to plot multiple categorical data in Excel

Tags: excel, charts

I have this data, which contains information from 0 to 10 on how good is a party, according to people interviewed.

The columns represent the counts of each value that the person answered.

> (Label of the Data)

Party_Name  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10

> (Observations)

PartyA  120 46  79  70  49  144 42  10  9   4   8

PartyB  119 38  74  79  51  135 39  19  5   1   1

The problem is that I have over 15 parties. What should be the easiest way to plot all of them?

I've tried plotting them like this:

[image]

But I'd would like keep the bars the same colors, and maybe plot the other parties on the same plot, but with 2 by row, or something like that, and also label the bars with the numbers from "0-10".
I hope I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a clustered column chart:

[image: clustered-column chart]

The way that you would set this up, would be to change the chart type to "Clustered Column":

[image: chart setup]

Then to add the data labels, you would right click on one of the bars, select "Add Data Labels." Then right click the bar again and select "Format Data Labels." It should pop open the right hand pane to edit details related to data labels. Check "Category Name" and then uncheck "Value."

[image: format data labels]